# Registry value with quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, registrykey

I need to insert a value into registry in a batch file. The value contains quotes and that makes it hard to insert.

```
set OPENCOMMAND="\"%JAVAHOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*\""
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d %OPENCOMMAND%
```

This results almost in the correct result except that the value contains quotes around it in the reqistry.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*"
```

That's what the registry contains and what it should contain is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVAHOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*"
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems many people have tried (at least my inbox had three new replies) and this one was the only one working :)